# Problems with libpcap - segmentation fault

Tags: visual-studio-code, segmentation-fault, libpcap

I'm having problems with the libpcap function "pcap_findalldevs".
The problem is when I run the code is gives a "segmentation fault".
The code is:

```
int listDevices()
{
    int res = -1;
    int count = 1;
    pcap_if_t *device;
    pcap_if_t **alldev;
    char e_buffer[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    res = pcap_findalldevs(alldev, e_buffer); //Gives "segmentation fault" here

    if (res == 0)
    {
        printf("Error reading list of devices: %s\n", e_buffer);
        return res;
    }

    if (alldev == NULL)
    {
        printf("No devices founded!");
        return 1;
    }

    device = *alldev;

    while(device != NULL)
    {       
        printf("%s\n", device->name);
        device= device->next;
    }

    pcap_freealldevs(*alldev);

    return 0;
}
```

Watching the variables, I can see that **alldev is giving an address of 0x0 while the others have "normal" addresses.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> `res = pcap_findalldevs(alldev, e_buffer);`

You have not given `alldev` a value here, so it's passing a random value to `pcap_findalldevs()`, causing it to crash.

What needs to be passed to `pcap_findalldevs()` is a pointer to a `pcap_if_t` variable, so you should do

```
res = pcap_findalldevs(&device, e_buffer);
```

If that call returns a value other than `PCAP_ERROR`, `device` will be set to point to the first element of a list of `pcap_if_t` structures - or to NULL, if no interfaces were found.  I.e., a return value of 0 means *success*, so you should do

```
if (res == PCAP_ERROR)
{
    printf("Error reading list of devices: %s\n", e_buffer);
    return res;
}
```

as the error check.

You can get rid of the `alldev` variable.

Comment: Sorry for the late replay but I had to stop the project for a while. Your answer did solve the problem. Thank you very much.